# Entity Framework with LINQ using CONTAINS in WHERE clause very slow with large integer list

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, list, entity-framework-5, contains

I have a function that first queries a function in the database that returns a list of employees that a user is allowed to see. This run in a couple ms. Using this list I query the employee table to get all the employees that this user is allowed to see. When I run the generated sql in query analyzer it takes only a few milliseconds. When it runs from entity framework it is taking over 8 seconds.

Initially I had a list of allowedEmployees but then read http://mikeinba.blogspot.ca/2009/09/speeding-up-linq-contains-queries-with.html and tried using a HashSet instead but the performace is still really bad. How can I get its performance similar to what it is in sql query analyzer? What am I doing wrong?

I am using SQL 2008 and EF5.0

```
public IQueryable<Employee> FindAllByWithPermissions(int eID, Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> predicate)
    {
        if (predicate != null)
        {
            HashSet<int> allowedEmployees = SecurityRepository.GetPermissableEmployees(eID);
            return DataContext.Set<Employee>().Where(predicate).Where(p => allowedEmployees.Contains(p.EmployeeID)).AsQueryable<Employee>(); ;
        }
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Predicate value must be passed to FindBy<T,TKey>.");
    }
```

It seems that when it writes the sql to have the IN clause it takes a long time. There are a few thousand permissable employees but why does generating the sql for it take so long?

Comment: Hey, can you put in some timer code around the actual query and compare it to SSMS, its always good to measure what the difference is. It will also help you know when its better

Comment: It takes 10799ms right now for the query to run. In SQL query analyzer it takes less than a ms. There are about 5500 records in the allowed employee list.

Comment: Where in your code do you have the timer block is it just around `DataContext.Set<Employee>().Where(predicate)....`?

Comment: I have it wrapped around a call to the FindAllByWithPermissions

Answer (score 0):

Return an `IQueryable` instead of a HashSet, and then `join` it with your Employee `IQueryable`.

```
var availableEmployees = SecurityRepository.GetPermissableEmployees(eID);
var allEmployees= DataContext.Set<Employee>();

query = from item in allEmployees.Where(predicate)
        join t in availableEmployees on item.EmployeeID equals t.EmployeeID
        select item;
```

Comment: The GetPermissableEmployee function does a call to a SQL function to get the list. You can't map sql functions into entity framework as far as I know. dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT * FROM DBO.GetPermissableEmployees(@ID)", new SqlParameter("ID", eID)).ToList<int>()

Comment: `Database.SqlQuery` returns an `IEnumerable`, which supports all of the linq methods.  Just remove the `ToList()` call.

Comment: Changing it to IEnumerable or IQueryable had a negligible effect

Comment: Did you include the code I posted above for creating a join instead of using `Contains`?

Comment: I would try your code Robert but how do I still include my predicate?

Comment: You can apply the predicate *after* the join, or on AllEmployee as `allEmployees.Where(predicate)`.  See my edit.

Comment: I tried your code above but I keep getting the error "The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection." no matter what I change the parameter name to in the function call

Comment: @user2430492: That's a really strange error to be getting.  My code assumes two IQueryable or IEnumerable collections, not two of something else.

Comment: I decided to just use a table in the DB to store the values. This allows me to just do a join. Brought it down from over 10 seconds to 2ms to get my results. Thanks for the help and ideas